# maven cannot access any package in my project

Tags: maven

I've tried anything I would find on the internet but nothing seems to work.

I am using Intellij with OpenJDK 17.0.2

The only error is cannot access *package* for every class in my project

I tried:

- Invalidating everithyng and restarting
- Restarting my pc
- Removing all the repositories in the .m2 folder
- Probably something else I don't remember

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.iseal</groupId>
    <artifactId>CPit</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>CPit</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>papermc-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.mrdarkness462</groupId>
            <artifactId>thepit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\ThePit-0.6.4beta - API 4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.simplix-softworks</groupId>
            <artifactId>simplixstorage</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.papermc.paper</groupId>
            <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.19-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue, and nothing I do fixes it.

Comment: Hey there, I fixed it but I don't remember how sorry... It was too long ago